# select one value from table to insert into new table plus other values

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server-2014

I have this stored procedure that does not return `@RefereeId` with the `getRefereeId` output parameter. Any suggestions? I get nothing returned for `getRefereeId` when running this query

```
   @Email nvarchar(50),
   @AssignerId int,
   @RefereeId Int Output,
   @DateCreated Datetime,
   @Active bit,
   @Invitation bit
as
begin
    Select @RefereeId 
    From Referee 
    Where Email = @Email

    Insert Into Assignment (AssignerId, RefereeId, DateCreated, Active, Invitation) 
    Values (@AssignerId, @RefereeId, @DateCreated, @Active, @Invitation)
End
```

VB code:

```
Dim strConn As String = "Data Source=mydatasource"
Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(strConn)

Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand("InviteReferee", Conn)
Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("Email", newEmail.Text))        
Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("Invitation", "True"))
Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("Active", "False"))
Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("AssignerId", AssignerId.Text))
Cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("DateCreated", DateTime.Now()))        

Dim getRefereeId As SqlParameter = Cmd.Parameters.Add("@RefereeId", SqlDbType.Int)
getRefereeId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

Conn.Open()
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually assign a column value to your output parameter!

Change your code to this:

```
Select @RefereeId = SomeSuitableColumnNameHere
From dbo.Referee 
Where Email = @Email
```

That way, you would be selecting one of your columns in `Referee` into the `@RefereeId` parameter that then gets sent back to the VB.NET caller.